# Mapping Mongo object to Realm DB Schema

Tags: mongodb, realm

I have a mongo document that looks something like:

```
interface Facility {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  settings: {
    readings: number,
    cooldown: number
    ... more stuff here
  }
}
```

Creating the Facility schema in realm is pretty straightforward, but I'm not sure what I should do for settings. I don't really need another realm schema for those. I didn't see any thing in the docs that talk about this specifically.

Comment: The question is a bit vague - are settings a property of Facility where each facility has a specific set of settings? If so, then why not just have readings and cooldown as direct properties of the Facility instead of a 'sub' property? It also helps us to know your coding platform so please add that tag so we can all talk 'the same language'. Also make sure you include a primary key and partition if you're going to be sync'ing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to additional docs, you have to use the `embedded objects` feature for this to work.

https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/node/embedded-objects

Comment: For future reference, you can [generate JSON Schema](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/enforce-a-document-schema) from your existing documents, after which you can [view the generated Realm models](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sync/configure-your-data-model#create-a-realm-object-model-from-a-realm-schema) in the SDKs tab in the UI.